# ICMP Fails after first packet

Tags: wireshark, icmp

I'm trying to ping any ip, other than my LAN IP & localhost, it fails except the first packet!!

Snapshot from CMD with the pings

[image: ICMP Failure]

But Wireshark capture shows that the ICMP is success!!

[image: Wireshark Capture]

Someone help me with this .. it is getting me crazy and also some of my own applications fail due to this!!

***EDIT:***

After sometime of non-stop ping:

```
Ping statistics for 173.194.39.33:
    Packets: Sent = 1202, Received = 1, Lost = 1201 (99% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 58ms, Maximum = 58ms, Average = 58ms
```

Comment: Is it the same story with something like www.google.com?

Comment: @AthomSfere yes .. with any domain or IP except my own 192.168.x.x and localhost (127.0.0.1)

Comment: Does it work as expected in Safe Mode with Networking? Can you perform those pings from your router?

Comment: I can ping from the router .. I also tried from different networks .. I didn't try safe mode .. It doesn't work with me .. takes ages to load

Comment: `General failure` makes me think about an issue i had on my laptop when Ethernet and Wifi adpater were started together...disabling one or other makes things works...does it could apply in your case ?

Comment: @user2196728 let me check .. I have a bridge between the wired and wireless .. I'll disable the bridge and test

Comment: @user2196728 same .. gives me `General failure` from second packet but wireshark shows success!

Comment: Beside the bride, try to disable the network adapter (Wifi or wired) by right click the interface and choose disable

Comment: done that .. all interfaces are disabled except the wireless .. I'll try with a cable in the next 30 mins .. when I have a router near me

Comment: @user2196728 still got the same .. I used a cable and still have the same issue

Comment: Wireless adapter still explicitely disabled right ? any third party security software (antivirus, firewall, antimalware) to disable and test again ? are we talking about a home or corporate network ? Can you try `ping -t` during one minute and send the result ?

Comment: I'm using a home network .. I tried the `ping -t` command it gave the same

Comment: @user2196728 I've edited the post, and placed the output of `ping -t`

Comment: and what about third party security software ?

Comment: @sikas - Run the command prompt as administrator (right click -> run as administrator) and then do the ping test again to see what the error is.

Comment: @Lawrence still the same while running as admin

Comment: @user2196728 I have windows firewall, comodo internet security and Kaspersky Small Office Security

Comment: @sikas : wow ! all these could explain your issue ! can you try to disable all these just temporarily and test again ?

Comment: @user2196728 OK got it now .. it is the comodo firewall .. Now I need to figure out which rule in it is doing this!

Comment: ok great, i am preparing a "generic" answer for you case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a firewall issue. Wireshark shows the ping replys are reaching your computer, but they are getting dropped before they reach the application (like CMD). Try disabling firewall(s).

Comment: It was indeed a problem with the Comodo Firewall .. I purged the rules and also removed PING.exe from the list the restarted the Application. Everything works fine now. Thanks!